# 32-bit dll not working in 64-bit os

Tags: dll, windows-7, contextmenu, 32bit-64bit

I created a dll file built (Project:win32 app, ATL and COM object using Visual studio 2008) in 32 bit. In win 7 32 bit OS, After registering my dll i'm getting "ABC" option in context menu(on right click). Now i move to win 7 64 bit OS. Dll loaded successfully, but i'm not getting "ABC" option on right click(in context menu). Can anyone please point me where i went wrong or any suggestions ?

**Note:** Right click on Folder gives "ABC" option.

Comment: Use check last error and display a message box if you get an error in your code on the call that adds that option?

Comment: Is it a shell extension (is the context menu shown in the explorer)? Did you compile it for 64bit? A 32bit shell extension doesn't run on Win64.

Comment: Yes i'm using shell extension! Yes itz working when i "compile for 64bit". But not working when compiled for 32bit... @martinstoeckli can u explain me why 32bitdll won't work in 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shell extension compiled for 32bit will run only in a 32bit process. The Windows Explorer of a 64bit Windows is a 64bit process, so it requires a 64bit shell extension.

If a 32bit application would use the fileopen dialog (on a 64bit Windows), the dialog would require a 32bit shell extension. So it's recommended that you install your extension like that:

- Win32: 32bit Shell Extension
- Win64: 64bit and 32bit Shell Extension

To do this, you have to give different GUIDS to the 32bit / 64bit shell extension. Hope that makes it a bit more clear.

Edit: As Raymond suggested, it seems that you can use the same GUID for both extensions.

Comment: Actually you can register them with the same GUID, because there are separate 32-bit and 64-bit registries. The 32-bit application will see the 32-bit registration and the 64-bit application will see the 64-bit registration. This makes LNK portability between 32-bit and 64-bit applications possible.

Comment: @Raymond Chen - Didn't know about this, i believed that you need different GUID'S. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Key is to use the two different versions of Regsvr32.exe.  Use c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe to register the 32-bit version.

Comment: @Hans Passant i tried that but i'm not able to see the context menu. i think what "martinstoeckli" said is correct.

Comment: To all Thanks a lot for your suggestions and solutions.

Comment: @Hand Passant - Ah well, sometimes i feel sorry for todays installers, they have more and more riddles to solve.

Comment: BTW as Hans mentioned above, there are two versions of regsvr32 and you need the one of the same bitness, however in most cases you don't have to worry about this because they will internally call the other if bitness does not match. The only perhaps exception is when you start regsvr32 under debugger: here you need to check that you are starting the right one.